# SSH service running on multiple ports with custom rules in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, systemd, services

I was working on setting up a server with SSH service running on multiple ports like say, port 22, and 5522 and these port should be having a different set of rules, ie: The rules we added for port 22 should not conflict with the rules for port 5522.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, the SSH service can be made to listen to multiple ports by adding the following line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
Port 22
Port 5522
```

In this scenario, you cannot define different rules for different ports.

One of the solutions I could find is to create a new service to run SSH service on port 5522 and then running the service as daemon.

To do so please follow the steps below:-

1. create a copy of the SSH service and name it, here I named the copy as `sshd_config_custom`

```
cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config_custom
```

2. Similarly, create a copy of the service too.

```
cp /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service /lib/systemd/system/sshd-custom.service
```

3. open `/lib/systemd/system/sshd-custom.service` using any comfortable editor and change

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
```

to

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_custom
```

And

```
Alias=sshd.service
```

to

```
Alias=sshd-custom.service
```

Save and exit the file.

4. Now you can add the line Port 5522 in /etc/ssh/sshd_config_custom and can make any required changes to this conf file.
5. Enable and start the custom service that we have created.

```
systemctl enable sshd-custom.service
systemctl start sshd-custom.service
```

Let me know if there are any other suggestions

Comment: congrats, this answer : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599941/sshd-different-configurations-for-different-ports

Comment: "you cannot define different rules for different ports": you can use the [`Match`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) directive in `sshd_config` to achieve that, at least for a subset of `sshd`'s configuration parameters. Nevertheless both of the approaches have pros and cons - e.g. two independent processes may offer better protection against crashes, misconfiguration and, possibly, some kinds of attacks, but require administrators to tailor service files for different system managers.

Comment: BTW: When you use `systemctl edit sshd-custom.service` your favourite `$EDITOR` is used automatically. Also you don't have to remember that tedious path :) Also manages overrides automatically. Use `cat` instead of `edit` to print the result.